# How to remove cardamom seeds from rice

Tags: rice

I love the taste of cardamom seeds, as does the family.

But I am the only person in the household who doesn't mind chewing the seeds as a part of the rice dish.

For flavoured rice, it's quite easy, but fried rice with mixed vegetables etc I always end up missing some.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using entire pods or just the loose seeds?

Comment: I've never used cardamom seeds before, but would grinding them with a Mortar and Pestle be viable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My typical method to add flavor, but not "bits", is to wrap the ingredients in a cheesecloth bag and remove it after cooking is done. Usually this is larger items than cardamom seeds (e.g. vegetables or bay leaves), but with fine enough cloth you should be able to add seasoning without adding texture.

Comment: The best option by far. The only other viable option is to deseed the cardamom pods, which takes more effort, and more pods (because there's no way in hell you're getting all the seeds), but can be worth the effort.

Comment: You can also find whole cardamom seeds in the spice aisle of some grocery stores (whole seeds, not ground, just removed from the pod).

Comment: Yes! The bundle of spices and herbs attached with a string or inside a cheesecloth is called a [bouquet garni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouquet_garni)

Answer (score 2):

When cooking rice cardamom pods will usually float to the surface and cook on the top. I've found that I can get almost all the pods out in just a few seconds by spooning them off the top of the rice.

Using black cardamom pods will also help as they are much bigger than green ones, meaning you use fewer of them and they are very easy to spot and pick out. I prefer the flavor too.

Answer (score 1):

For stir fries etc consider adding the cardamom seeds to the oil while heating....much as one temporarily adds garlic and ginger. Allow to release their essential oils and then strain out before proceeding with the recipe. You can also make infused cardamom oil by crushing the seeds and adding to the oil. It will last indefinitely when stored in a cool dry place. The oil will be infused in a couple of days and ready for use. The sme technique can be used to flavor salt.

Comment: You can just edit your answers, no need to delete and post a new copy.